# Problem creating template function alias with const value template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

This is simplifed version of code that doesn't compile. I know that const value and value signature functions existing both are ambiguous, but I need two different functions based on constness of value template arguments. But I didn't expect to have problem taking somewhat alias of f1. It works with all const type references, but not with const value.

```
template<class... ARGS_T>
void f1(ARGS_T...) {
    std::cout << (std::is_const_v<ARGS_T> || ...) << std::endl;
}

template<class... ARGS_T>
constexpr void(*f2)(ARGS_T...) = f1<ARGS_T...>;

class C {};

int main() {
    f1<const int, const C>(1, C());
    (*f2<const int, const C>)(3, C());
    return 0;
}
```

Both versions of f1 are instantiated without problems and have different addresses, why I can't create two different pointers to them this way?

I am using g++ (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0 on Windows

Compilation errors:

```
C:/Alias/main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr void (* const f2)(int, C)<const int, const C>':
C:/Alias/main.cpp:15:8:   required from here
C:/Alias/main.cpp:9:17: error: no matches converting function 'f1' to type 'void (* const)(int, class C)'
    9 | constexpr void(*f2)(ARGS_T...) = f1<ARGS_T...>;
      |                 ^~
C:/Alias/main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate is: 'template<class ... ARGS_T> void f1(ARGS_T ...)'
    4 | void f1(ARGS_T...) {
      |      ^~
```

Comment: Please add the compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a compiler bug in GCC, which is related to `const` in function parameters. Firstly, note that `const` in function parameters is not part of the function type:

> After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level *cv-qualifiers* modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type.

- [[dcl.fct] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5)

This means that `void(int)` and `void(const int)` are the same type. The same applies to the function pointer types `void(*)(int)` and `void(*)(const int)`. All major compilers accept the following code, as they should:

```cpp
void fi(int);
void fci(const int);

void(*pfi)(int) = &fi; // OK
void(*pfci)(int) = &fci; // OK

void(*pcfi)(const int) = &fi; // OK
void(*pcfci)(const int) = &fci; // OK
```

For some reason, GCC doesn't correctly perform this type adjustment when dealing with variadic templated function types:

```cpp
// note: using a single T instead of ARGS_T... works
template<class... ARGS_T>
void f(ARGS_T...) {}

void(*pfi)(int) = &f<int>; // OK
void(*pfci)(int) = &f<const int>; // error

void(*pcfi)(const int) = &f<int>; // OK
void(*pcfci)(const int) = &f<const int>; // error
```

*See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/b1fbo6Y9T)*.

Clang and MSVC compile this code, but GCC doesn't. The type of `f<const int>` is `void(const int)` which is the same type as `void(int)`, so this code should compile, just like the first example.

---

*Note: I have submitted a GCC bug report. See [GCC Bug 111662](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111662).*